# Is there a way to expand my inventory?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

When exploring, before I move down to the next floor I tend to run into the problem of having my inventory full, this is a bit of a pain when I use up a number of spots for healing items to be better prepared for exploring.

I am wondering if there is a way to expand my inventory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know of from a play-through on classic mode, there is no way to expand your inventory space. It will always be locked at 60 spaces. There are a few ways you can make your inventory stay less full in general though. Try:

- Identifying any Grimiore stones you have in your inventory. Once identified at your mansion, they will no longer use up inventory space.
- Selling all drops from monsters. Other than a few requests, there is no reason to hold on to monster drops.
- Store and sell extra equipment. There is very little reason to keep unused weapons in your inventory, and the same goes for armor.
- Don't carry as many healing items. Chances are, unless you're playing on expert, you won't ever need more than about 10 healing items in your inventory. A few Nectars for revival, a few Amrita for TP recovery, maybe a Therica B or two. If you have a decent healer, you won't need to drag around dozens of Medicas and Therica A.